# Creating a dynamic view using PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding view creation.

Here is my question:

I need to generate a report using a view which takes data from two tables lets say Table_A and Table_B.

Sample data in Table_A:

```
empno  empname 
----------------
1      abc       
2      xyz
```

Sample data in Table_B:

```
Empno element_name    Amount
--------------------------------
1      Basic_Salary    10000
1      Medical_bill    500
2      Basic_Salary    20000
2      Medical_bill    500
```

Now, My expected result is

Output:

```
Empno   Empname     Basic_Salary   Medical_bill  Total_sum
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       abc              10000         500         10500

2       xyz              20000         500        20500
```

Note 1:

I am generating a report by passing a parameter like quarterly report or monthly report.

Suppose here lets say, I need a report of 3 months details then
I need to sum the basic salary of an employee

Please help me with this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Ok..Let me make it clear. Basic_Salary and Medical_bill are the rows in table_A. But my result should have them as Columns. And I will be generating a report either on monthly basis or yearly basis or quarterly basis. So The Basic Salary of a person for an year will be 12*(20000) in this case. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Has this data model been forced on you, or do you have the authority to improve it?  TableA seems to have two purposes - it holds both employee data and 'element' data (which means the employee data is duplicated).  I'd have a separate employee details table- the problem will become easier to solve

Comment: Yae ...I can improve it.If that is the case would you please tell me what can be the approach.

Comment: OK - see my answer for one way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your reply to my comment...  I would recommend you update the data model so you have a table of employees and a table of elements with values (a purist may go further and have three table - employees, elements, and emp_element_values).  This means you can update employee data without knowing or caring about the elements table (at the moment a change of name would result in multiple updates to tableA which cannot be what you intend.

```
WITH
 emp (empno, empname) AS
  (SELECT 1,'abc' FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 'xyz' FROM dual
  )
,elements (empno, element_name, element_value) AS
 (SELECT 1,'Basic_Salary',20000 FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1,'Medical_Bill',500 FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2,'Basic_Salary',50000 FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2,'Medical_Bill',1000 FROM dual 
 )
SELECT
 emp.empno
,emp.empname
,sal.element_value * :number_of_months       basic_salary
,med.element_value * :number_of_months         medical_bill
FROM
 emp
,elements       sal
,elements       med
WHERE 1=1
AND emp.empno = sal.empno
AND sal.element_name = 'Basic_Salary'
AND emp.empno = med.empno
AND med.element_name = 'Medical_Bill'
;
```

So, in the above I have not included effective_date 'cause I do not know whether this is a attribute of emp or element.

Comment: Ok...Thank You so much...And i need one more help now i have some 1000's of records in the table.It is not possible to use select statements for each row.Can you help me how can i do it

Comment: Do you mean you have 1000s of different types of elements?

Comment: No, I have 1000's of employees and around 50 types of elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query:

```
---Table data preparation
with tabl_A (empno,  empname, effective_date, elem_name )
        as 
            ( Select 1 ,     'abc',       '13-jun-2016',  'Basic_Salary' from dual
              UNION ALL
              Select 1 ,     'abc',       '13-jun-2016',  'Medical_Bill' from dual
              UNION ALL
              Select  2,      'xyz',       '5-may-2017',   'Basic_Salary' from dual
              UNION ALL
              Select  2,      'xyz',       '5-may-2017',   'Medical_Bill' from dual ),
      tabl_B ( Empno ,Basic_Salary, Medical_Bill) as
              (
                select 1,      20000,        500 from dual
                UNION ALL
                select 2 ,     50000,        500 from dual                            
              ),   
     ---Table data preparation over              
   tabl_c (empno, empname, effective_date,sal,mbill  ) as 
   ( 
   SELECT A.empno,
         A.empname,
         A.effective_date,
         b.Basic_Salary * &num_mnth AS sal,
         b.Medical_Bill * &num_mnth AS mbill
    FROM tabl_A A 
    INNER JOIN tabl_B B 
    ON a.empno = b.empno
    GROUP BY A.empno,
         A.empname,
         A.effective_date,
         b.Basic_Salary,
         b.Medical_Bill )

 SELECT c.*, (sal + mbill) AS Total_Sum
  FROM tabl_c c;
```

On execution, this would ask to enter the number of months as input and result would be then displayed.

Output:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for num_mnth: 3
old  22:          b.Basic_Salary * &num_mnth AS sal,
new  22:          b.Basic_Salary * 3 AS sal,
Enter value for num_mnth: 3
old  23:          b.Medical_Bill * &num_mnth AS mbill
new  23:          b.Medical_Bill * 3 AS mbill

     EMPNO EMP EFFECTIVE_D        SAL      MBILL  TOTAL_SUM
---------- --- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 abc 13-jun-2016      60000       1500      61500
         2 xyz 5-may-2017      150000       1500     151500
```